# Горизонтальный скролл в таблице Padination на горизонтальный скролл

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

слишком много столбцов, из-за чего появляется горизонтальный скролл, какие есть варианты его убрать, если смысл через php делать, но может есть и другие варианты через JS чтоб он автоматом добавлял padination
[image: На картинке видать внизу горизонтальный скролл, можно ли его через js как слайд сделать или padination добавить]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте пагинацию если не нравится скрол, в чем проблема?

Comment: вот через JS можно добавить пагинацию?

Comment: Можно, как вариант, поместить каждую колонку в блок и потом через JS смотреть количество блоков, делить на необходимое для страницы и отображать нужное количество блоков и страниц.

Comment: Можно как через JS так и через PHP, в чем Вы лучше разбираетесь на том и пишите

Comment: Вы хотите заменить **горизонтальный скролл** на **pagination**? Это как так?

Comment: Я тож не понимаю как горизонтальный скролл в менять на пагинацию.... Может просто сделать в стиле гугл календаря ну или как-то так?
Собственно сам пагинатор на php https://github.com/jasongrimes/php-paginator